# Impossible to locate an element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find one of these elements (vote up or vote down):

```
<div class="votingWrapper ">
            <span class="voteBtn voteUp " data-postid="c4fcff79-7f73-493c-b6d8-f05ff1962897"></span>
            <span class="postRank">
                <span class="rankWrapper wrapper_up" data-points="1320">+1.3k</span>
                    <span class="rankWrapper wrapper_down" data-points="512">-512</span>
            </span>

                <span class="voteBtn voteDown " data-postid="c4fcff79-7f73-493c-b6d8-f05ff1962897"></span>
        </div>
```

I tried to locate it by class, id, xpath (a lot of types) but I got NoSuchElementException for all attempts.

`element = driver.find_element_by_id("c4fcff79-7f73-493c-b6d8-f05ff1962897")`

`element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("voteBtn voteDown ")`

`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c4fcff79-7f73-493c-b6d8-f05ff1962897"]/div[1]/span[3]')`

I searched for 3 hours how to do that but I failed. It's impossible.

Can anyone give me some tip?

Comment: Your second xpath seems correct. First and third are incorrect as there is a data-postid attribute but not an id. Check if these elements are inside an iframe. If so you need to switch to that before firing the selectors.

Comment: @Grasshopper, man... The ***ing iframe, hahah! Finally, man... Now its working like charm. I'm crying ;'^D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following XPaths (in case they are not in a frame):

to find voteUp:

```
//span[contains(@class,"voteBtn voteUp")]
```

to find voteDown:

```
//span[contains(@class,"voteBtn voteDown")]
```

If they are  `inside a frame` (check whether the elements you are trying to find, are `child` elements of an `iframe` tag), then first `find the frame` and then `switch` to it. then use the XPath to find elements.

Comment: Man... The frame!!! Hahah! Finally, man... Now its working like charm. I'm crying ;'^D
Thank you!

Comment: You really should be using a CSS selector for something simple like this, e.g. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.voteBtn.voteUp"));`. The problem with using XPath here is that your contains requires an exact string match so if the CSS classes change order or a class is inserted between the two, etc. it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You have pass single class at a time

```
element_up = driver.find_element_by_class_name("voteUp")
element_down = driver.find_element_by_class_name("voteDown")
```

Comment: I already did it. The names of classes are `"voteBtn voteDown "` and `"voteBtn voteUp "`

Comment: @EduardoM his point is that `.find_element_by_class_name()` takes a *single* class name... you can't use compound names. When you tried that, you likely got an error stating the same. This method should work also and is actually better than the accepted answer but Florian's is the best, most specific answer.

Comment: @JeffC, I had tried this way too, just as he said, before this topic. My problem was that the elements were inside a frame. Naveen's answer was the only one that noticed this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Using space in html tags is usually deprecated but your issue can be resolve easily. 
In CSS, you can access a div with a class name with a name separate with a space using a dot. 
Example :

```
<span class="voteBtn voteUp " data-postid="c4fcff79-7f73-493c-b6d8-f05ff1962897"></span>
```

can be access in CSS file by :

```
.voteBtn.voteUp {}
```

You can use the same technic with your selenium and as a one liner :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.voteBtn.voteDown")
```

Comment: I added "span" to the final CSS selector because it makes it just a little more specific and less likely to grab unwanted elements. It may not matter in this case, but it might in others.

Answer (score 0):

CSS for vote up: `div.votingWrapper > span`

or

```
 span[class*='voteUp']
```

CSS for vote down: `div.votingWrapper > span:nth-child(3)`

or

```
span[class*='voteDown']
```

Comment: Same issue... Unable to locate element